# Duplicating multiple records in table with primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, arraylist, duplicates

I am working with duplicating multiple records in table 1 with primary key which has a reference with table 2 (foreign key)

Consider table `employee` with columns (eid(primary key),ename,dept,dept_code).

Table 2 `employee_address` with columns (eaid(primary key), eid(foreign key), city, country)

Now the task is the table 1 (ie. employee) may have number of values with different department codes.

Suppose `dept_code` may be 1 or 2 like so and so.

Now with both the table with some data look like this

**EMPLOYEE** table

```
Eid(pk) ename   dept    Dept_code       
100      Sss    Cse      1      
101      Aaa    Cse      1      
102      Bbb    Cse      1      
103      Ccc    Eee      2      
104      ddd    it       3
```

**EMPLOYEE ADDRESS** table

```
Eaid (pk)   Eid (fk)    city    country
1            100         NY      Us
2            100         NY      Us
3            100         NY      Us
4            101         CALIF   Us
5            102         DC      Us
6            102         DC      Us
7            103         NJ      Us
```

now the thing is i have to duplicate all the records in employee table where dept_code=1 and duplicate records dept_code should be = 5.

And the foreign key referencing to employee address table (ie. here in the current document 100,101,102) in the table 2 has to be duplicated number of times those foreign key value present in table 2.

I have to get the output like this

Employee table

```
Eid(pk) ename   dept    Dept_code       
 100     Sss    Cse       1     
 101     Aaa    Cse       1     
 102     Bbb    Cse       1     
 103     Ccc    Eee       2     
 104     ddd    it        3     
 **105   sss    cse       5     
 106     aaa    cse       5     
 107     bbb    cse       5**
```

Employee Address table

```
Eaid (pk)   Eid (fk)    city    country
 1            100        NY       Us
 2            100        NY       Us
 3            100        NY       Us
 4            101       CALIF     Us
 5            102        DC       Us
 6            102        DC       Us
 7            103        NJ       Us
 **8              105        NY       Us
 9            105        NY       Us
 10           105        Ny       Us
 11           106       CALIF     Us
 12           107        DC       Us
 13           107        DC       Us**
```

Now I have to get the output like this.

Conditions for this task is,

- no for loop
- hitting a database should be as minimal as possible
- can use java or if posssible in sql query itself.

I tried with various ideas nothing worked out.

Help me out in this.

Comment: How does this relate to java?

Comment: `I tried with various ideas nothing worked out` please show or explain what you tried.

Comment: I'd start with select into and a subquery. The only tricky part is to use the right primary key. Like:

`select
  (select max(eid) + 1 from employee ), ename, dept, 5
  into employee
from (select * from employee where dept_code = 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, these two queries will work.  They use tSql window functions, if you are not using Sql Server then you will need to find the equivalent.

Edited to answer comment from OP-

If you want to create new tables:

```
Select * Into EmployeeNew From (
    Select  *
        From Employee E 
    Union All
    Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By eid) + (Select Max(eid) From Employee),
            ename, dept, 5 dept_code
        From Employee 
        Where Dept_Code = 1) A

Select * Into EmployeeAddressNew From (
    Select  A.*
        From Employee E
        Join EmployeeAddress A On A.eid = E.eid
    Union All
    Select  A.eaid + (Select Max(eaid) From EmployeeAddress),
            Dense_Rank() Over (Order By E.eid)  + (Select Max(eid) From Employee),
            City, Country
        From Employee E
        Join EmployeeAddress A On A.eid = E.eid
        Where E.Dept_Code = 1) A
```

If you only want to insert 'new' records into the original tables:

```
Insert Employee 
    Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By eid) + (Select Max(eid) From Employee),
            ename, dept, 5 dept_code
        From Employee 
        Where Dept_Code = 1

Insert EmployeeAddress       
    Select  A.eaid + (Select Max(eaid) From EmployeeAddress),
            Dense_Rank() Over (Order By E.eid)  + (Select Max(eid) From Employee),
            City, Country
        From Employee E
        Join EmployeeAddress A On A.eid = E.eid
        Where E.Dept_Code = 1
```

Comment: Thank you!. Its working. And one more thing. i wanted to insert this is database. You are just selecting the things and displaying.

Comment: Hi this is my actual second query.

Comment: select A.*
from t017_fournisseur_inconnu T
Join t0171_fournisseur_inconnu_lig A on A.cap_rnpo_id = T.cap_rnpo_id
Union All
select A.cap_rnpo_lig_id + (select max(cap_rnpo_lig_id) from t0171_fournisseur_inconnu_lig),
Dense_Rank() over (Order By T.cap_rnpo_id) + (select max(cap_rnpo_id) from t017_fournisseur_inconnu),
cd_site, prorata, compte, libelle, ville, pays, codepays, client_scopp,
cli_fin, cc, oa, pa, ca, decision, origine, dateupdate, ipn 
from t017_fournisseur_inconnu T 
Join t0171_fournisseur_inconnu_lig A on A.cap_rnpo_id = T.cap_rnpo_id
where T.scenario_id=1;

Comment: i am getting an error like this  ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 20 Column: 57.         i think this is due to the table 2 structure.. because primary key in this table lies in second column.  correct those mistakes in it.

Comment: I can not recreate the error without having the data and structure of your tables.  Ambiguously defined usually refers to having a column name in the select list that is present in two tables that are joined but without the alias prefix.  For example eid would need to be either E.eid or A.eid.  As for problems with inserting data into primary keys you may need to set identity insert on.

Comment: Hi. while inserting values into table 2(ie. EmployeeAddress table). Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TRAINING.SYS_C0033086) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.
   This error is thrown.

Comment: It sounds like you are adding to employeeaddress before adding to employee. You can only do that if you drop the foreign constraint and add it back after your all done.

Comment: No i have already executed the first query.. which creates some number in records in Employee table. The database is committed. After that when i try to execute the second query i am getting the error, I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: 3 rows inserted.
committed.
Error starting at line 49 in command:
insert into address
 Select  A.id + (Select Max(id) From address),
        Dense_Rank() Over (Order By E.eid)  + (Select Max(eid) From emp),
        city, street
    From emp E
    Join address A On A.eid = E.eid
    Where E.Dept_Code = 1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TRAINING.SYS_C0033086) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.

Comment: I think I see what is happening.  In the second query we are getting max(eid) from employee.  After you insert new records into employee that is getting thrown off.  Options would be to build two temp tables first then insert employees then addresses from the temp tables, or you could try switching to select max(eid) from employeeaddress.